# Cordova/PhoneGap lock screen music controls

Tags: cordova, plugins, lockscreen, lockscreenwidget

I am creating a multimedia iOS/Android app using Cordova and would like have control over the application (previous, next, play/pause controls) when screen is locked.

Does someone know if there is a Cordova plugin allowing to do this or will I have to implement  a plugin for each targeted platform ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This plugin looks like what you're looking for: https://github.com/shi11/RemoteControls

Installing via CLI: `$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/shi11/RemoteControls.git`

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  var RemoteControls = window.plugins.RemoteControls;
  artist = "Daft Punk";
  title = "One More Time";
  album = "Discovery";
  RemoteControls.updateMetas(artist,title,station);
}
```